# flash builder (flex 4): how can i add facebook-actionscript-api to my project

Tags: apache-flex, facebook, flash-builder, facebook-actionscript-api

I'd like to write a program using the facebook-actionscript-api.

The google code's website of facebook api shows that it provides .swc files for flex 3.4 or the sources.

how can I add them to my Flash Builder project ?
Do I need to compile the sources ?

How can I use the swc file in my project ?

any information regarding this subject would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!!!

Comment: I had been using the SWC which Adobe provides but I don't think it's updated with the recent OpenGraph stuff which FB has come out with. Check out the bigspaceship's AS3 library. I have found it to be much better than the SWC and also decreases the SWF file size a lot. http://www.bigspaceship.com/blog/labs/bss-classes-flash-and-the-fb-graph/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, a new Flex project contains a libs folder by default, which is the preferred way to manage SWCs within your project. Simply drop the Facebook SWC within the libs folder and it will be compiled with your project.

You can manage what libraries are compiled with your Flex project by right-clicking your project folder in Flash Builder and selecting "Properties", "Flex Build Path" from the left-hand side and finally the "Library path" tab. The libs folder should already be an item on this list, but you can add it if it isn't or just add the individual SWC file.